# How do I convince the borrow checker that a function call result will not outlive &self

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Since posting the original question I have managed to boil the example down to :

```
    trait Bacon {
        fn foo(&mut self, x: usize) -> Result<usize, f32>;
    }

    pub struct Banana<'a> {
        phantom: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
    }

    impl<'a> Banana<'a> {
        fn inner_foo(&'a mut self, x: usize) -> Result<usize, Box<dyn Error + 'a>> {
            Ok(x)
        }
    }

    impl<'a> Bacon for Banana<'a> {
        fn foo(&mut self, x: usize) -> Result<usize, f32> {
            self.inner_foo(x).map_err(|_| 0.0)
        }
    }
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> /home/thoth/src/rust-esp32-experiments/http-camera/webcam-applib/src/lib.rs:97:18
   |
97 |             self.inner_foo(x).map_err(|_| 0.0)
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> /home/thoth/src/rust-esp32-experiments/http-camera/webcam-applib/src/lib.rs:96:16
   |
96 |         fn foo(&mut self, x: usize) -> Result<usize, f32> {
   |                ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> /home/thoth/src/rust-esp32-experiments/http-camera/webcam-applib/src/lib.rs:97:13
   |
97 |             self.inner_foo(x).map_err(|_| 0.0)
   |             ^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> /home/thoth/src/rust-esp32-experiments/http-camera/webcam-applib/src/lib.rs:95:10
   |
95 |     impl<'a> Bacon for Banana<'a> {
   |          ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> /home/thoth/src/rust-esp32-experiments/http-camera/webcam-applib/src/lib.rs:97:18
   |
97 |             self.inner_foo(x).map_err(|_| 0.0)
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `&mut Banana<'_>`
              found `&mut Banana<'a>`
```

I think my code is safe, and the `Box<dyn Error+'a>` will not outlive `&self`, but there might be some other lifetime issue I have overlooked.

kmdreko mentions that `'a` is more constrained than`'_`, but I'm not sure how to rework `inner_foo` to capture the lifetime characteristics of the Box contents.

I tried changing the return type of read_inner to `Result<usize, Box<dyn Error + 'static>>` , but that gave me a lot of errors, and suggested that I add `'static`' to elements of the where clause (ES, EI), which would ripple up through the call hierarchy.  I was hoping to use the map_err as a firewall to avoid that.

```
cargo 1.62.1-nightly (a748cf5a3 2022-06-08)
rustc 1.62.1-nightly (e4f2cf605 2022-07-19)
```

How can I convince the compiler that my code is safe?

Comment: This is missing code required to reproduce the problem, but you seem to have a lifetime `'a` associated with your type `CameraBody` so your `read_inner` self looks like: `&'a mut CameraBody<'a, ...>`. The problem is not with the `Box<dyn Error + 'a>`, the problem is you cannot pass off `&mut self` as `&'a mut self` since the latter is more constrained.

Comment: Try introducing a different lifetime parameter `read_inner<'b>(&'b mut self, ...) -> Result<..., Box<dyn Error + 'b>>`.

Comment: Are you sure that the error will really depend on the lifetime of `self`? We are missing the code which produces the error, but it seems far more likely the lifetime of the error does not rely on self. You may want to instead try `Box<dyn Error + 'static>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have currently moved past this problem without solving it using the `<'b>` technique suggested by kmdreko.  I had to modify large chunks of the rest of the app to make it work (and patch the crate that specifies the trait), so the original question is still of interest.